# How to fix Array to string conversion error

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

I am using multiple select on my html select form with the objective of inserting two ids in one sell.

I’m getting this error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\allprojects\projects\Colégios\users\teacher\addscore.php on line 33
insert into cursosprogramas (departamento, codigocurso, diurno, contacto, pos_laboral, contacto2, proc_por) values ('100', '120','Array', '88839', '7', '5353','2')Query failed.
```

Code:

```
<select type=text name=diurno[] value="<?php echo $name; ?>" multiple size=2><br>

    <?php
    $sql = "select * from professore1 where coordenacao='$coordenacao' order by coordenacao;";

    for ($i= 0; $i < pg_numrows($res);$i++) {
        $name = pg_fetch_result ($res, $i, "name");
        $numero = pg_fetch_result ($res, $i, "numero");
        echo "<option value = '$numero'>$name</option>";
    }
    ?>

</select>

<?php
$idd=$_SESSION['jpgwapo'];
$id=$_POST['id'];
$grdid=$_POST['grdid'];
$diurno=$_POST['diurno'];   
$contacto=$_POST['contacto'];
$pos_laboral=$_POST['pos_laboral'];
$contacto2=$_POST['contacto2'];

$con = @pg_connect ("port=5432 host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=a");

$sql = "insert into cursosprogramas (departamento, codigocurso, diurno, contacto, pos_laboral, contacto2, proc_por) values ('$id', '$grdid','$diurno',
 '$contacto', '$pos_laboral', '$contacto2','$idd')";
$res = @pg_query ($con, $sql);
if ($res == NULL){
    echo "Query failed.";
    exit (0);
}   
?>
```

So far I've tried to follow some samples but I still don't understand how it works.

Comment: The answer lies in the error notification: `values ('100', '120','Array',...` Somehow `$diurno` is an array, and you try to use it as a string.

Comment: Thanks @Michal, how can I fix it?

Comment: I can't answer that, because I don't know what's in `$_POST['diurno'];` Try to `var_dump($_POST)` and see if something is wrong.

Comment: _“with the objective of inserting two ids in one sell”_ - you mean, you want to put both values into one column of one record, separated by a comma? Then you need to get your array content into that format first, for example using implode. (Security concerns, and the violation of proper normalization, left aside here.)

Comment: Yes @CBroe the idea is to store two datas or ids in one cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$diurno=isset($_POST['diurno']) ? (array) $_POST['diurno'] : '';
if (is_array($diurno)) {
    $diurno = implode('|', $diurno);
}
```

Try with this code. I think will work properly.
You receive that error because you are trying to save  to database, but this value is array and you cannot save it to the database.
You have a two option to implode values with unique delimeter and then save $select to the database or to convert array to json and save it to the database and after that you can use data.

Comment: Thanks @plamen Penchev. It's giving: parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE), expecting

Comment: where? maybe is missing semicolon

Comment: Sir @Plamen Penchev the error is somewhere here:$diurno=isset($_POST['diurno']) ? array $_POST['diurno'] : '';

Comment: put "array" in brackets $diurno=isset($_POST['diurno']) ? (array) $_POST['diurno'] : '';

Comment: Sir @Plamen Penchev I have another error but is not on the code. I troubleshoot the error on SQL Shell and it is saying invalid input syntax for integer : "6|3". Do I have to change my DB?

Comment: yes change column type to "varchar" because 6|3 is not a valid integer

Comment: Thanks it works. But there is another error with my join table because before I added two ids I was only adding one id and it was working. Now that I’m adding two ids it’s giving me error on the join table. How to fix it? The error: warning: pg_quer: Query failed: error: operator does not exist: integer=character varying LINE

Comment: $sql2="select cursosprogramas.codigo,cursosprogramas.disciplina, cursosprogramas.legenda,cursosprogramas.r,cursosprogramas.t, cursosprogramas.tp,cursosprogramas.pl,cursosprogramas.ts, cursosprogramas.total,cursosprogramas.ms,(select name from professore1 p where p.numero=cursosprogramas.diurno) as diurno_nome, cursosprogramas.contacto,(select name from professore1 p where p.numero= cursosprogramas.pos_laboral) as pos_laboral_nome, cursosprogramas.contacto2 from cursosprogramas as cursosprogramas where cursosprogramas.ano='$ano' and cursosprogramas.codigocurso='$grdid';";

Comment: let's be clear diurno represents ids, which  are user ids and u want to assign a item to more than a one user, or I miss something. Your column is foreign_key which u need to connect to another table, right?

Comment: Yes, represent ids. I have a multiple select on my form which I can select only one id or two ids and add them to my table on the DB. From that table where I'll add the ids I'll do join table so that I can display the names and not the ids(numbers)

Comment: So, how can I do it @Plamen Penchev?

Comment: wait I will send u a picture because, here is awful

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/J2HMbHJ.png I think your code should be something like that and remove implode function, you don't need anymore this function

Comment: thanks @Plamen Penchev I'm having query failed. the error:insert into cursosprogramas (departamento, codigocurso, curso, codigo, disciplina, legenda, ano, r, t, tp, pl, ts, total, ms, diurno, contacto, pos_laboral, contacto2, proc_por) valuesQuery failed. do I have to change again the database from varchar to int?

Comment: yes, changed to int, but why query failed I don't know, you need to check it and customized depends on your needs, maybe is some smal error like ','. Try to run it on phpmyadmin and you will find errors more easily

Comment: Sir @Plamen Penchev would you please check your codes again. I still have query failed

Comment: put comma after ".$idd.")here put comma"; when u set $data in foreach loop

Comment: Sir @Plamen  it looks like it is not getting the value of diurno that I have assigned on my form, because it gives this error (insert into cursosprogramas (departamento, codigocurso, diurno, contacto, pos_laboral, contacto2, proc_por) valuesQuery failed. If there is no value on the diurno sample: diurno =[ ];
And it gives me this error (insert into cursosprogramas (departamento, codigocurso, diurno, contacto, pos_laboral, contacto2, proc_por) values(100,120,6,7575,5,5757,2);(100,120,3,7575,5,5757,2);Query failed.)
if I have to give the value of diurno manualy like this: diurno = [6,3];

Comment: (100,120,6,7575,5,5757,2);remove semicolon from here need to be 
 comma(100,120,3,7575,5,5757,2) and add validation before sending value to the database